# Prevent joomla api to log deprecated warning

Tags: logging, joomla, warnings, joomla2.5

I have joomla 2.5 which log many deprecated warnings like `Error::raiseNotice() is deprecated.`
So I result width a big log file. Can I turn off this option, and log just my own exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

You can always place an error reporting condition in your index.php like:
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Or you can edit error.php in your joomla directory, and

```
public static function raiseNotice($code, $msg, $info = null)
{
    // Deprecation warning.
    JLog::add('JError::raiseNotice() is deprecated.', JLog::WARNING, 'deprecated');

    //return JError::raise(E_NOTICE, $code, $msg, $info);
}
```

disable this function to raise deprecated warnings...

Comment: There no way to configure JLog in way that it log just `JLog::ERROR` Instead of logging all levels?