# 3gb file deprecated.php in Joomla logs

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've got problem with my Joomla. In logs folder I found huge file named "deprecated.php" which takes allmost 5GB of my server space. I removed this file about week ago and now this file have more than 1GB. It's Joomla 2.5 website contain about 4k articles.

Any ideas what that file is? Cause uncle Google didn't help me at this time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649052/prevent-joomla-api-to-log-deprecated-warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649052/prevent-joomla-api-to-log-deprecated-warning)?

Comment: have you tried opening the file to see what errors are being stored in it?

Comment: @Lodder Opening 1GB file from the server? You kidding right?

Comment: try deleting it again, let the file be created again and after 1 day, download it and open it

Comment: Or download it after 30 minutes, since it is probably building up pretty quickly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extensions may be using deprecated code and this is OK but you should check your error reporting settings:

- Check Site -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Error Reporting is
  set to "System Default".
- Check Site -> Global Configuration -> System -> Debug System is set
  to "No".

You could also check php.ini and .htaccess for error reporting settings.

If all else fails, you can stop the deprecated errors being logged by adding a line to your php.ini file like this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED
```

References:

- https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/admin-tools/10873-deprecatedphp-running-amok.html
- [Prevent joomla api to log deprecated warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649052/prevent-joomla-api-to-log-deprecated-warning?lq=1)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php